# swift: Xcode Couldn't Generate Swift Representation for Facebook framework

Tags: facebook, swift, bridging-header

I am try to integrate facebook in my app using Swift. I have download the Facebook SDK in my app. the fecebook SDK is in Objective-C.  And for that to connect Objective-C files in Swift I am creating an Bridging-Header.h file and import the FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h and FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h file .

But, could not connect to it when open it I get an error message as follows:

[image]

I was set the following in Build Settings:

1. Objective-C bridging Header.
2. Framework search paths

But I didn't connect to it.

If anyone has any clues, that would be great.

Comment: Did you find what was the problem?

Answer (score -2):

Clean using Cmd+option+shift+k and then re-build.

Comment: After doing "Cmd+option+shift+k and then re-build" try restarting xcode. This did work for me.

Comment: Hi, It's work first time but not work second time in xcode 7.3. Have you idea for same ?   @JitendraSingh